# How can you verify in UWP if a user has purchased a subscription when he is offline?

Tags: c#, uwp

[MSDN mentions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#purchase-a-subscription-add-on) how one should implement subscription check. But it does not mention if this works offline or not. If it doesn't work, then how does one verify if a user purchased a subscription when the user has no internet connection?
I imagine that this scenario can't be tested because the testing scenario would return a sample response anyway, it won't query the actual server.

```
private async Task<bool> CheckIfUserHasSubscriptionAsync()
{
    StoreAppLicense appLicense = await context.GetAppLicenseAsync();

    // Check if the customer has the rights to the subscription.
    foreach (var addOnLicense in appLicense.AddOnLicenses)
    {
        StoreLicense license = addOnLicense.Value;
        if (license.SkuStoreId.StartsWith(subscriptionStoreId))
        {
            if (license.IsActive)
            {
                // The expiration date is available in the license.ExpirationDate property.
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // The customer does not have a license to the subscription.
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [StoreAppLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense) object returned by this method([GetAppLicenseAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getapplicenseasync)) provides access to `licenses for add-ons` and other info, such as whether the license is active. **If this method is called while the device is offline, it returns the cached value of the current licenses on the device.**

Comment: In my experience, that is not working very well: start an app with wifi on, license active. Switch to airplane mode, start the app again, license is inactive...